# Can Dart SDK be Installed on Windows 8

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm wondering if Dart SDK can be installed on **Windows 8** because I'm confused about the [System Requirements](https://dart.dev/get-dart#system-requirements), They said it supported on **Windows 10** and Architectures **x64, ia32**.

So Why Flutter which includes the full Dart SDK can be installed on **Windows 7 SP1**, [See Flutter Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)

Comment: Flutter meanwhile requires ***Windows 10 or later (64-bit)***, see [Windows install | Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows "Windows install | Flutter").

Answer (score 1):

If anyone interested, the linked Flutter Docs mention Win7 no more, and it is normal as MS doesn't officially support that any more - but that doesn't mean that a certain thing won't run on it. I have a toy machine that has 32-bit Win7, and I could install the latest Dart SDK and was able to `dart run hello_world.dart`, so it should work on Win8 as well - it is a different question though that which bits of the technology will crash, if they prefer >= Win10. One needs to experiment by trial-and-error...

Comment: Did you mean *`if they prefer < Win10`*?

Comment: @Wolf I meant the manufacturer, possibly it is not clearly stated.

Comment: Oh, I see; maybe this could be improved by a slight rewording (BTW: this answer helped me decide if I should try Flutter on Win8, here's one of the first steps to reinstall PowerShell (v7) by hand)